# Maven - copy all the dependencies of a project and and transitive dependencies

Tags: maven

I’m new to maven. (I have searched for hours for the answer but without luck. **mvn dependency:copy-dependencies do not solve my problem**)
I need to copy all the dependencies of a project (in the form of jars) and if one of my jars depend on another artifact copy that artifact as well.

Example project1 pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>project1</groupId>
        <artifactId> project1.utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <name> project1. utils </name>
    
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>project2</groupId>
                <artifactId>project2.artifact</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <index>true</index>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Build-Number>${buildNumber}</Build-Number>
                                <Revision>${Revision}</Revision>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

“project1” have a dependency of project2.artifact.jar. When I use “mvn dependency:copy-dependencies”, I get project2.artifact.jar **but I do not get project3.artifact.jar that is a dependency of “project2”**.

I do not have the pom of project2, but it is installed in my local repository.

How can I get all the dependencies of project 1 including the second jar (“project3.artifact.jar”)?

Pom of project2 would look something like this, but I don't have it when I go to a client. So I install project2.artifact.jar, project3.artifact.jar manually using "mvn install".

Project2 pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>project2</groupId>
    <artifactId>project2.artifact</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <name>project2.artifact</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>project3</groupId>
            <artifactId>project3.artifact</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <index>true</index>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Build-Number>${buildNumber}</Build-Number>
                            <Revision>${Revision}</Revision>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
</plugins>

</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you post project2 POM?

Comment: For what purpose do you need to copy the jar files? Would you like to run the app ?

Comment: Tunaki - i edited the question and added the pom of project2, though i don't have it when i'm with a client.
khmarbaise - i need the copy to let a client compile the code ofproject1 and run project1.utils.jar (i preinstall on his computer project1.artifact.jar, project2.artifact.jar using mvn install).

Answer (score 1):

Please use the latest version of dependency plugin:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy-dependencies
```

If not works please check:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:list
```

`copy-dependency` goal copies the same artifacts which is resolved and displayed by `tree` and `list` goals.

For testing I prepare project3 pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>project3</groupId>
    <artifactId>project3.artifact</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I have such directory structure:

```
pr1
   pom.xml - from question

pr2
   pom.xml - from question

pr3
   pom.xml - as shown above
```

Now I do:

```
cd pr3
mvn clean innstall

cd ../pr2
mvn clean innstall
mvn dependency:tree
```

`dependency:tree` output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ project2.artifact ---
[INFO] project2:project2.artifact:jar:2.0
[INFO] \- project3:project3.artifact:jar:3.0:compile
```

So project2 depends on project3
next:

```
cd ../pr1
mvn clean install
mvn dependency:tree
```

`dependency:tree` in project1 output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ project1.utils ---
[INFO] project1:project1.utils:jar:1.0
[INFO] \- project2:project2.artifact:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO]    \- project3:project3.artifact:jar:3.0:compile
```

So it is also ok.

And now copy:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

With result:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy-dependencies (default-cli) @ project1.utils ---
[INFO] Copying project3.artifact-3.0.jar to ...\pr1\target\dependency\project3.artifact-3.0.jar
[INFO] Copying project2.artifact-2.0.jar to ...\pr1\target\dependency\project2.artifact-2.0.jar
```

If you also want to copy project1 artifact add it to dependency in project1  pom.xml

```
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>project2</groupId>
        <artifactId>project2.artifact</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>project1</groupId>
        <artifactId>project1.utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

Now:

`mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies` we have:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy-dependencies (default-cli) @ project1.utils ---
[INFO] Copying project3.artifact-3.0.jar to ...\pr1\target\dependency\project3.artifact-3.0.jar
[INFO] Copying project2.artifact-2.0.jar to ...\pr1\target\dependency\project2.artifact-2.0.jar
[INFO] Copying project1.utils-1.0.jar to ...\pr1\target\dependency\project1.utils-1.0.jar
```

Comment: unfortunately even with version 2.10 the result is the same (and it does not appear in tree, list).

Comment: Slawomir Jaranowski - thanks for your time! but what i need is this:
i would like to install project3.artifact-3.0.jar, project2.artifact-2.0.jar (copy to local repo),
then create just project1 with a dependency of project2 (but without the code of project 2 and 3) .
now, how do i get the dependencies of project1 (the installed jars)?
(sorry if my description was not clear at the beginning)

Comment: @Mishta if you don't have project source you can prepare simple pom, what you already did in this question and install poms for those artifacts.